# How to show the set of all algebraic real number is countable

Tags: real-analysis

A real number $x$ is said to be *algebraic* if there is a nonzero polynomial $p$ with rational coefficients such that $p(x)=0$. Show the set of all algebraic real number is countable.

Let $Z$ be the set of all algebraic real number.

Things I know:

(1)The denumerable union of denumerable sets is denumerable.

(2)A polynomial of degree $n$ has at most $n$ zeros.

(3)$\mathbb{Q}$ is denumerable.

(4)A subset of a denumerable set is denumerable.

Hint, think of the sets:

$A$) set of zeros of a given rational polynomial.

$B$) set of rational polynomials of a given degree.

$C$) set of all rational polynomials.

My thought is that if I can show that $Z\subseteq A\cup B\cup C$ and that $A,B,$ and $C$ are denumerable then I have shown Z is countable.

The set $A$ is clearly finite from (1), therefore denumerable.

Is my logic for the proof sufficient and how can I say $B$ and $C$ are denumerable?

Comment: You seem to be taking the union of very dissimilar sets.  While the roots of any one rational polynomial $A$ are a finite subset of $Z$, you don't get all roots of all rational polynomials by taking a union with $B$ or with $C$.  See this previous Question, [Proving the countability of algebraic numbers](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/50655/proving-the-countability-of-algebraic-numbers), for a detailed proof.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems to me that this pivots on your (1):

> The denumerable union of denumerable sets is denumerable.

You can use this to successively extend denumerability from $\mathbb Z$ to

- $\mathbb Q$
- The polynomials over $\mathbb Q$.
- The roots of the polynomials over $\mathbb Q$.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, for every polynomial $P$ of degree $n$, we have at most $n$ different roots. Associate to every polynomial $P$ the set $M_P=\{1,..,m\}$ where $m$ is the number of roots ($M_P$ being empty if there is no root), and to every root $r$ the number $i$ which indicates that $r$ is the $i$-th smallest root.

Let $\mathbb{P}_n:=\mathbb{Q} \times... \times \mathbb{Q} \times I_n$, where $I_n=\{1,...,n\}$ and $\mathbb{Q}$ appears $n$ times.

Now, choose for every algebraic number $r$  a polynomial $P_r$ for which it is the root. Let $\mathcal{A}$ be the set of algebraic numbers and define:

$$f: \mathcal{A} \rightarrow \bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \mathbb{P}_n,$$

by maping $r$ to $(a_l,a_{l-1},...,a_0,i_r)$, where the $a_j$ are the coefficients of $P_r$ and $i_r$ is the number $i$ described above.

$f$ is clearly an injection, and $\bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \mathbb{P}_n$ clearly countable.

OBS: Note also that I use AC some times in this proof (for example, countable unions of countable without further analysis). For a proof that doesn't use AC, see [this post.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/178227/59234)

Answer (score 0):

If  you  know  these  two  more  results :

$1.$  Finite  product  of  countable  sets  is  countable .

$2.$  Countable  union  of  countable  sets  is  countable .

Any  algebraic  number  is  a  root  of  a  polynomial  in  rational  coefficients with  degree  $n$  for  some  $n\in \mathbb N$

So  we  can  find  their  number  if  we  can   find  the  number  of  polynomials  with  rational  coefficients.
Now   fix  a  natural  number  **$\ \ n$** .

The  cardinality  of the  set  of   polynomials  of  degree  **$n$**  with  rational  coefficients  is   cardinality  of  the  set  $$(\prod_{i=1}^{n} \times_{i} \ \  \mathbb Q)=\mathbb Q\times \mathbb Q\times ........\times \mathbb Q(n\ \ \ fold\ \ \   product)$$ and  this  cardinality  is  *countable*  from  *result* $1).$

Then  the  cardinality  of  the  set  of  *all*  polynomial   with  rational  coefficients  of  *any*  degree   is  *cardinality*  of  the  set  $$\cup_{n=1}^{\infty}(\prod_{i=1}^{n} \times_{i} \ \  \mathbb Q)$$   which  again  is  countable  according  to  *result* $2).$ as  $$(\prod_{i=1}^{n} \times_{i} \ \  \mathbb Q)$$  is  countable as  we  already  saw .

So  concluded  that  there  are

Answer (score 0):

Well a polynomial $p$ of degree $n\geq1$ with rational coefficients can be thought of as a point in $\Bbb Q^{n+1}$, so say $p(x)=x^2-2\iff (1,0,-2)\in \mathbb{Q}^3$. Now if we want to count the roots would could simply consider them as points in $\Bbb Q^{n+1}\times \Bbb N_*$, where the last index will number the root, and we'll give the last number a subscript $*$, so as not to cause confusion between points. So up to some arbitrary numbering say for $p$ above we'll have two points $p_1=(1,0,-2,1_*)\iff \sqrt{2}$ and $p_2=(1,0,-2,2_*)\iff -\sqrt{2}$. Now it is also true that the cartesian product of a finite number of countable sets is countable, so each set $\Bbb Q^{n+1}\times \Bbb N_*$ is countable.

So for purely counting arguments you could consider the roots of polynomials as such a disjoint union of sets $\sqcup_{n=1}^\infty \left(\mathbb{Q}^{n+2}\times \Bbb{N}_*\right)$, and a countable union of countable sets is countable.

Of course you are over counting since the polynomials aren't all irreducible, so the same roots appear more than once, and also you have polynomials which have complex roots that are included, and also because you aren't using the entirety of the natural numbers for each degree of polynomial.

However since a subset of a countable set is countable, we're still fine as we can find an *injection* from our set of algebraic real numbers and the above mentioned set (the disjoint unioned one), send the algebraic number to the point associated to it's minimal polynomial, and the number assigned to that root.

**Sidenote** Now this is generally not the way you'd think of polynomials in algebra. Usually you'd think of the polynomial ring $\Bbb{Q}[x]$ over the field $\Bbb Q$, where the elements are written $$(1,0,2,-\frac{1}{2},0,0,\ldots)\iff 1+0\cdot x+2\cdot x^2-\frac{1}{2}\cdot x^3,$$ the dots meaning the rest are zero. But again usually the ring only contains elements whereby after some point all the entries are zero, so the same argument applies.